# MacOS: Set Dark-Mode for other User?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, terminal

Is it possible to set dark mode for other users?

Lets say im logged in as User A (admin), and i want User B (admin) to have dark mode.

I know theres an applescript/osascript command, but that one requires user interaction from the user, that the command gets called by. (so sudo -u B ..... doesnt work)

Greets

Comment: Is there a particular reason to override the user's preferences?

Comment: Its in my own interest, just experimenting around with mobile configuration profiles, however you can't set dark mode in there.